# Copy trx files stored in Test Plans into another location

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to copy all the trx files that my VSTest tasks are creating into one location in order to count the total number of tests run using a powershell script. The problem is that, VSTest task is creating all the trx files in Test Plans and these are available only there. Is there any way to copy them into another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VSTest task, there is an argument `Test results folder`, which can specify the folder to store test results files:

[image]

Then you can copy the test results to the location you want via `Copy files` task:

[image]